# postgres/postgreSQL FATAL: database "ew_dev" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to get echowaves up and running on mac os x 10.6.4 and I followed all the instructions here https://github.com/echowaves/echowaves successfully but when I run rails s I get the following error `FATAL:  database "ew_dev" does not exist` Do I need to create the database? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing:

```
rake db:create:all
```